C# WPF - Issue when opening a hyperlink when .exe is executed by system user
I have a WPF application including an Installer project, which when compiled in release mode, generate a .msi file. This .msi file execute some basic CustomActions after the install through the following class.
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class InstallerClass : Installer
{
    public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        KillOtherNotifsProcess();
        NotificationLog.Info($"CustomActions.Install...");
        base.Install(stateSaver);
        NotificationLog.Info($"CustomActions.Install OK");
    }

    public override void Commit(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        NotificationLog.Info($"CustomActions.Commit...");
        base.Commit(stateSaver);
        string targetDir = Context.Parameters["targetdir"].Trim();
        StartApplication(targetDir);
    }

    private void KillOtherNotifsProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            string processName = "MyApplication";
            IEnumerable<Process> otherNotifsProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
            if (otherNotifsProcesses.Any())
            {
                foreach(Process curOtherNotifsProcess in otherNotifsProcesses)
                {
                    NotificationLog.Info($"Found running instance of {processName}, killing process ID: {curOtherNotifsProcess.Id}");
                    curOtherNotifsProcess.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            NotificationLog.Error("KillOtherNotifsProcess", ex);
        }
    }

    private void StartApplication(string targetDir)
    {
        try
        {
            string NotifsFilePath = Path.Combine(targetDir, "MyApplication.exe");
            NotificationLog.Info($"Starting application: {NotifsFilePath}");
            //KillOtherNotifsProcess();
            Process processToStart = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = $"\"{NotifsFilePath}\"",
                    UseShellExecute = false, // Must be false to hide the window
                    CreateNoWindow = true, // Ensures no window is created
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden // Hide the window if it's still created
                }
            };

            NotificationLog.Info($"processToStart.Start {NotifsFilePath}");
            processToStart.Start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            NotificationLog.Error("StartApplication", ex);
        }
    }
}


As you can see in the Commit() function, I launch StartApplication().
The thing is, when the application is started after install completed, it runs the .exe as System user, which seems to cause some issues about opening hyperlinks.
In my app, to open Hyperlinks after a click on an element, I just do this :
public static void OpenUrlInDefaultBrowser(string url)
{
    string pattern = "<a\\s+href=[\"'\\s]*([^\"'\\s>]+)[\"'\\s>]+.*?</a>";
    Match match = Regex.Match(url, pattern);
    if(match.Success)
        url = match.Groups[1].Value;

    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(url)
        {
            UseShellExecute = true
        };
        Process.Start(sInfo);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Une erreur s'est produite : {ex.Message}", "Erreur", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

But it result to this pop-up showing up :

Even if I select one browser and click 'Always', the pop-up will still show if I click links then.
This behavior is not present if I close the app and launch it manually as my current Windows user : in this case, the link opens directly in default browser.
I've tried to launch the app after installation as the current Windows user via a solution similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147868/7226035, but when I click on a link I have an error telling me the browser profile could not have been loaded. So I tried in addition to load the Windows user profile but it didn't improve things.
I've searched on various forums and it seems that no one had this problem, so maybe I'm missing something...
All ideas are welcome!

Sounds like you want to launch your application un-elevated; that's not trivial, but there are a lot of suggestions around. For example: c# - How do you de-elevate privileges for a child process - Stack Overflow

Thanks for the suggestion @Richard Deeming. I tried something like this as I said at the end of my post, but maybe I missed something and maybe it wasn't done in the right way, because my app was launched as non-elevated but it couldn't launch default browser in some cases : On my machine it was working, but on another machine which had Firefox as default browser, it was launching the browser, then I had the following error after clicking on a link : "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inacessible."

I found a solution which does the trick : Creating a scheduled task with Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler package. The task has to be created by the current Windows user in order to appear on desktop.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

namespace CustomActions.Utils
{
    public static class TaskSchedulerHelper
    {

        const int WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = 0;
        const int WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = -1;

        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(
            IntPtr hServer,
            int sessionId,
            WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass,
            out IntPtr ppBuffer,
            out int pBytesReturned
        );

        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
        private static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pointer);

        private enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
        {
            WTSUserName = 5
        }

        public static bool LaunchTask(string targetExe)
        {
            try
            {
                string taskName = "MyAppLauncher";

                string currentUser = GetActiveUserName();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentUser))
                {
                    NotificationLog.Error("Unable to get the active user.");
                    return false;
                }

                NotificationLog.Info($"currentUser for scheduledTask: {currentUser}");

                using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
                {
                    
                    if (ts.GetTask(taskName) != null)
                        ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask(taskName);

                    
                    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
                    td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Task allowing the app to launch after install.";

                   
                    td.Principal.UserId = currentUser;
                    td.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken;

                    td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(targetExe, null, null));

                    td.Triggers.Add(new TimeTrigger
                    {
                        StartBoundary = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15),
                        EndBoundary = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
                    });

                    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, td);
                    return true;
                }
            } 
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                NotificationLog.Error(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        

        public static string GetActiveUserName()
        {
            IntPtr buffer;
            int strLen;

            // Get the username for current session
            if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out buffer, out strLen) && strLen > 1)
            {
                string username = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);
                WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
                return username;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}

I just called LaunchTask() in the StartApplication() of InstallerClass and it did the trick.
